# When using python's selenium to access the website under proxy conditions, it is displayed: ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, proxy

When using python's selenium to access the website under proxy conditions, it is displayed: ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED。

But when I use the seleniumwire library, it can be entered. But the available proxy does not work, it is still the ip of my own computer

```
import re
import time
import random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
#from seleniumwire import webdriver
from my_fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options




#https://github.com/jhao104/proxy_pool（Get free proxy under this project）
def get_proxy(url,num):
    i=1;proxy_ip=[]
    while i <= num:
      r = requests.get(url)#Randomly get an agent
      proxy = r.text
      ip = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+', proxy)[0]
      i+=1
      proxy_ip.append(ip)
    proxy_arr = []
    for p in proxy_ip:
      proxy_str = f'--proxy-server={p}'
      proxy_arr.append(proxy_str)
    return proxy_arr


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
#chrome_options.add_argument('headless')  # 设置option


#get proxy
url='http://127.0.0.1:5010/get/'
proxy_arr=get_proxy(url,5)

#The request header is automatically obtained randomly
ua = UserAgent(family='chrome')
user_agent = ua.random()
headers1 = {"User-Agent":  user_agent}

proxy = random.choice(proxy_arr)  
print(proxy)
chrome_options.add_argument(proxy)  
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headers=%s' % headers1)

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=s)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': 'Object.defineProperty(navigator, "webdriver", {get: () => undefined})'})


driver.get('https://www.bing.com')
```

I want to solve the problem of entering the website under proxy